# Progress bar update during a network call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I am trying to implement horizontal Progress bar update during a network call. The API which I am using to do the network call only has to callback onSuccess and onFailure. It takes somewhere around 0.5 - 3 seconds to finish.

My issue is, how do I quantify the progress of such networking call to update my UI or to be specific what do I pass inside                 publishProgress() method inside my doInBackgropund implementation of the AsyncTask

Comment: Well, if your API does not give you progress information, you cannot show progress information. Ideally, use a better API. FWIW, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/OkHttpProgress) demonstrating showing progress updates with OkHttp3.

Comment: using any other API is not an option for me. There must be some way to fill up that bar. It doesn't have to be the accurate representation of the progress. Only if  i can fill it to give a UI feedback to the user that something is happening, that should be enough for me.

Comment: How about an indeterminate `ProgressBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't have to be the accurate representation of the progress. Only if i can fill it to give a UI feedback to the user that something is happening, that should be enough for me.

Personally, I'd still use an indefinite progress indicator. Users are pretty savvy about detecting BS from app developers.

That being said, you could use a variation of [one of Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox): every 500ms or so, cut the remaining percentage of work in half. So:

- at time index 0, show progress as 0% (100% remaining)
- at time index 500ms, show progress as 50% (50% remaining)
- at time index 1000ms, show progress as 75% (25% remaining)
- at time index 1500ms, show progress as 87.5% (12.5% remaining)
- etc. until the work is done

You might need to tweak the update frequency and the amount to cut. But basically you keep showing incremental progress throughout the work, until your API stuff is completed. As opposed to a linear progression (e.g., 10% every 500ms), you're guaranteed with this algorithm to never *quite* get to 100%, so there's always room for more progress. Admittedly, you eventually get into sub-pixel adjustments in the `ProgressBar`... :-)

To do the periodic work, the simplest thing is a `postDelayed()` "loop", as it requires no extra threads:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Threads/PostDelayed/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/post/PostDelayedDemo.java), and note that my period is 5000ms, which is too long for your use case)